# Resigning an Array in an if block that is never ran makes it nil

Tags: ruby

Ok, so I have a function, which if a variable ends up not being an array,
makes it an array, with the value of the original variable as the first and
only element
iv written the code as following

```
variable = userInputOfSorts()
puts JSON.pretty_generate(variable) # Prints expected output, array with 2 values
if (!variable.is_a?(Array)
    variable = [variable]
end
puts variable # nil
```

Now, I have put debug statements inside this if block(puts statements) and can confirm that it is not running.

With the debug statements inside the if block, which I am certain is not running, I tried to comment out the reassignment statement

```
# variable = [variable]
```

)

shouldn't matter, that statement is never ran anyway. But by god, it worked. Obviously, I need that statement there for when the user input is not an array.

So my problem is, the reassignment statement that is never ran, makes the variable null.

I have an example written, that one can run to verity this. It seems to have something to do with classes/attr_reader, as it worked when just writing it outside a class, and running it.

```
require 'JSON'


class MainClass
  attr_reader :mock_input

  def initialize(input)
    puts "hello"

    @mock_input = input

    # Print with JSON or puts
    puts "-------"
    if (mock_input.is_a?(Array))
      puts JSON.pretty_generate mock_input
    else
      puts mock_input
    end
    puts "-------"

    if (!mock_input.is_a?(Array))
      puts "Converting to array..."
      mock_input = [mock_input]
    end

    # Print with JSON or puts
    puts "-------"
    if (mock_input.is_a?(Array))
      puts JSON.pretty_generate mock_input
    else
      puts mock_input
    end
    puts "-------"
  end
end

MainClass.new ["hello", "world"]
```

Comment: Provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Of course, sorry. Done!

Comment: if (!variable.is_a?(Array) missing a closing paren?

Comment: By the way: `a = Array(a)` will convert `a` to an array, unless it is already an array, in which case it leaves it unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a [bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11103), and got an answer from one of the developers. Apparently, in ruby, commenting out code in if blocks that are evaluated to false should be able to affect your program. AKA, this is not a bug, its a "feature"

But,

I found a solution

So, the original problem is

```
require 'JSON'


class MainClass
  attr_reader :mock_input

  def initialize(input)
    puts "hello"

    @mock_input = input

    # Print with JSON or puts
    puts "-------"
    if (mock_input.is_a?(Array))
      puts JSON.pretty_generate mock_input
    else
      puts mock_input
    end
    puts "-------"

    if (!mock_input.is_a?(Array))
      puts "Converting to array..."
      mock_input = [mock_input]
    end

    # Print with JSON or puts
    puts "-------"
    if (mock_input.is_a?(Array))
      puts JSON.pretty_generate mock_input
    else
      puts mock_input
    end
    puts "-------"
  end
end

MainClass.new ["hello", "world"]
```

changing the line

```
mock_input = [mock_input]
```

to

```
@mock_input = [@mock_input]
```

Fixes it

PS: as @Wayne Conrad pointed out, I could have just used `Array(mock_input)` instead of the if statement entirely.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly shorter implementation to convert input to an array if it isn't already one:

```
def input_to_array(input)
  [*input]
end
```

Using your original code:

```
variable = userInputOfSorts()
puts JSON.pretty_generate(variable) # Prints expected output, array with 2 values
variable = [*variable]
puts variable # nil
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work as an alternative to covert input to array.
What i want is that, it the input is, say
    "some string"
to become
    ["some string"]

Comment: Added it into your original example.

Comment: This gives the same error, and "variable" and ends up being nil. Thanks though.